# sql & django: Making aggregation on database level

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Hello I am having the following situation in my models:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    name

class SetOfItems(models.Model)
    name

class Item(models.Model):
    package(FK)
    setofitems(FK)
```

And the problem I am trying to solve is to simplify queries from SetOfItems. E.g. in case I would need to get a package name from SetOfItems, I would need to write something like 
SetOfItems.objects.values('item__package__name'), which actually does not work, well in admin site (e.g. if I am creating an extra field there).

So what I am looking for is to store the information about Packages in SetOfItem model without making a direct relation (as I think that if I will put a FK there the data integrity will suffer, e.g. it will be possible to have on package inside Item and another one in SetOfItems)..

So maybe there is some possibility to have SQL view, or something like this... to have a table column automatically pre-filled from other table? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Item is the through table in a many-to-many relationship between Package and SetOfItems. So you should declare it as such:

```
class SetOfItems(models.Model):
    packages = models.ManyToManyField(Package, through='Item')
```

This doesn't change your actual table structure at all, but it allows you to do `my_package.setofitems.all()`.

Comment: Well this will raise quite a few queries if I would want to display packages in SetOfItems admin

Comment: You mean in the changelist? If you're worried about that, override `get_queryset` to fetch a QuerySet that uses `prefetch_related` to get all packages.